# Problems with C # Lists - RemoveAt

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am practicing with C # Lists in Unity and I have encountered a problem.
My test script, instantiates 5 prefabs which are added in a gameobject list. I then wrote a code that generates a random int and from that number moves the prefab instantiated with that index (indexof). Everything works correctly, but the method that moves and deletes the prefab is repeated for all the gameobjects in the scene with an index higher than the one chosen. I enclose the two scripts to better explain the problem. (I would need the unlist method to be done only once.

how can i solve this problem and remove one item from the list at a time? (one each time the button is pressed, not all as it is now. Thanks)

script:

- NpcController: Added in each instantiated prefab
- ListCOntroller: added in the scene.

---

```
    public class ListCOntroller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cubePrefab;
    private GameObject cubeInstance;
    public static List<GameObject> cubeList = new List<GameObject> ();

    public TextMeshProUGUI checkText;

    public static event Action chooseNpc;
    public static int randNpcValue;

    int rand;
    private void Start()
    {
        for(int i =0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cubeInstance = Instantiate(cubePrefab, new Vector3(i, -2, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            cubeList.Add(cubeInstance);
        }
    }

    public void CheckListText()
    {
        checkText.text = "Npc in list: " + cubeList.Count.ToString();
    }

    public static void SelectRandomCube()
    {
        
        randNpcValue = Random.Range(0, cubeList.Count);
        chooseNpc?.Invoke();
    }

    
}
```

---

public class NpcController : MonoBehaviour
{

```
void Start()
{
    ListCOntroller.chooseNpc += NpcEvent;
}

private void NpcEvent()
{

    if (ListCOntroller.cubeList.IndexOf(gameObject) == ListCOntroller.randNpcValue)
    {
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 2, 0);
        DeleteFromList();
        
    }
}

private void DeleteFromList()
{
    ListCOntroller.cubeList.RemoveAt(ListCOntroller.randNpcValue);

    Debug.Log($"Delete from list: {ListCOntroller.randNpcValue}");
    
}
```

}

---

**the int random number generated in the attached images is: 2**

[image]

[image: button pressed once.]

Comment: first of all, a nice well formatted question, well done. Regarding the issue, your code looks fine to me, i can't really spot an issue i'm afraid... is the log message also printed multiple times? could it be that the button invokes the chooseNpc func. multiple times somehow?

Comment: There's alot of problems with that code. 1) `ListCOntroller` may be instantiated more than once 2) `ListCOntroller` should be a singleton, however the way it is written isn't Unity-singleton safe 3) using `static` with reference types 4) using `static` with Unity reference types such as prefabs can lead to your code referencing objects that have already been destroyed by Unity

Comment: When using `static` in Unity beware - [thar be dragons](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/DomainReloading.html).  Unity is a **CLR Host** whereby it can and will **zap** out the **Primary App Domain** along with all your objects **including singletons** not just during runtime but also whilst using the **Editor**.  See also _[Details of disabling Domain and Scene Reload](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfigurableEnterPlayModeDetails.html)_.

Comment: @MickyD I actually had trouble destroying an instantiated object that used static methods and variables. How can I get around this problem? (unfortunately I don't know any other solutions to manage the events of an instantiated object than those of using static events and methods).
I am a newbie in unity, I apologize for the trivial questions

Comment: @sommmen thanks, I try to do my best to make it easy to read and understand my problem :)
I entered a debug message on pressing the button and it is invoked once, the problem would seem to be the event that is invoked for each object, so the indexof is always updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74401790/7111561) in general I don't really see the purpose mixing the the logic into two different scripts.

You have one for storing a list and raising an event and the other one listens to the event and manipulates the stored list -> This doesn't sounds right.

You could as well simply do `why don't you pass a long the the according object into the event in the first place and rather do something like

```
public class ListCOntroller : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Singleton instance
    private static ListCOntroller _instance;
    // Read-only getter
    public static ListCOntroller Instance => _instance;

    // pass in the target object reference instead of doing things index based
    public event Action<GameObject> chooseNpc;

    public GameObject cubePrefab;

    // THIS is the list controller -> nobody else should be able to manipulate this list
    private readonly List<GameObject> cubeList = new ();

    public TextMeshProUGUI checkText;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(_instance && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this);
            return;
        }

        _instance = this;
    }
    
    private void Start()
    {
        for(int i =0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cubeInstance = Instantiate(cubePrefab, new Vector3(i, -2, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            cubeList.Add(cubeInstance);
        }
    }
    
    public static void SelectRandomCube()
    {
        if(cubeList.Count == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Trying to pick item from empty list");
            return;
        }

        var randomIndex = Random.Range(0, cubeList.Count);
        var randomItem = cubeList[randomIndex];

        // remove from the list yourself instead of relying on others to work correctly
        cubeList.RemoveAt(randomIndex);

        // pass along the target object
        chooseNpc?.Invoke(randomItem);
    }
}
```

and then

```
public class NpcController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start()
    {
        ListCOntroller.Instance.chooseNpc += NpcEvent;
    }
    
    private void NpcEvent(GameObject target)
    {
        // check if you are the target object
        if (target == gameObject))
        {
            // adjust your position - you don't care about other NPCs or the existence of a list
            transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 2, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the code had some errors but I solved it by setting both the list and the event as static.
if i wanted to insert a gameobject with a trigger and on contact with this trigger delete the object from the list, can i recall an event from the NPC code?

Answer (score 1):

Because events are executed one after another.

Let's say you have 3 NPCs: `NPC0, NPC1, NPC2`

Now the random number you choosen is 1, when NPC1's `NpcEvent` runs, `ListCOntroller.cubeList.IndexOf(gameObject)` is 1 which equals to the `randNpcValue`, and then NPC1 will be removed from the list.

Note that now the list has 2 items left: `NPC0, NPC2`. Next NPC2's `NpcEvent` runs in turn, at this time, `ListCOntroller.cubeList.IndexOf(gameObject)` is still 1 because the list has only 2 items, so NPC2 is also removed from the list.

A solution is you can change the `randNpcValue` to an invalid value when a NPC is removed.

```
if (ListCOntroller.cubeList.IndexOf(gameObject) == ListCOntroller.randNpcValue)
{
    transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 2, 0);
    DeleteFromList();
    ListCOntroller.randNpcValue = -2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you have explained very clearly what happens when the event is called, now everything is clearer. Your code works, it could probably be even better using a try-catch, right?

Comment: try-catch? why??? try-catch is used to catch exceptions, but there is no exception thrown in the code. But I found an problem in my answer please beware, `randNpcValue` cannot be set to -1, because `IndexOf` returns -1 when it cannot find the object.

Comment: "randNpcValue cannot be set to -1, because IndexOf returns -1 when it cannot find the object."  I meant just this error, using try-catch instead the code works fine.